# Open cv , Run code in tutorial of Finding contours in your image?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I'm just now starting to learn how to use the openCV libraries. I've downloaded and installed openCV 2.4.10 , and have run an example " [in tutorial of Finding contours in your image](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html#find-contours) " using visual studio 2010. The code compiles, but every time I run it, it crashes,[and I get the showing error in this image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOxds.png) which is as the following message:

> Windows has triggered a breakpoint in EdgeDetection.exe.
>
> This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in >EdgeDetection.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
>
> This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while EdgeDetection.exe has focus.
>
> The output window may have more diagnostic information.

I don't know, what is the reason.Here's the offending code:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat src; Mat src_gray;
int thresh = 100;
int max_thresh = 255;
RNG rng(12345);

/// Function header
void thresh_callback(int, void* );

/** @function main */
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  /// Load source image and convert it to gray
 // src = imread( argv[1], 1 );
    src=cvLoadImage("fish.bmp");
  /// Convert image to gray and blur it
  cvtColor( src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
  blur( src_gray, src_gray, Size(3,3) );

  /// Create Window
  char* source_window = "Source";
  namedWindow( source_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( source_window, src );

  createTrackbar( " Canny thresh:", "Source", &thresh, max_thresh, thresh_callback );
  thresh_callback( 0, 0 );

  waitKey(0);
  return(0);
}

/** @function thresh_callback */
void thresh_callback(int, void* )
{
  Mat canny_output;
  vector<vector<Point> > contours;
  vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

  /// Detect edges using canny
  Canny( src_gray, canny_output, thresh, thresh*2, 3 );
  /// Find contours
  findContours( canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

  /// Draw contours
  Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( canny_output.size(), CV_8UC3 );
  for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
     {
       Scalar color = Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255) );
       drawContours( drawing, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point() );
     }

  /// Show in a window
  namedWindow( "Contours", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( "Contours", drawing );
}
```

the breaking appears at line :

```
    findContours( canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );
```

So,I would like you to help me.

Comment: It is a little bit hard to know what went wrong without the knowing the line that generated the break point, can you hit the break button, and see which line it is stopping?

Comment: it appears at the line : 
>     findContours( canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

Comment: That is kind of weird, are you in debug mode? if not, can you try debug mode? opencv has a lot of asserts that may help you identify the problem.

Comment: yes, I am in debug mode. Error Message appears at that line.